# Android Expanded ListView Selected Item icon change

Tags: android

Any one please suggest, How to change icon image of selected item icon in Expanded Listview? In my senario if once click selected item ,previous icon change to normal state and selected item icon change to selected state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ExpandableBaseAdapter's **`getGroupView`**, there will be argument called **`isSelected`** strong text

So by using that argument, change your view or background based on your need.

```
if(isSelected){
image.setBitmap(R.drawable.my_drawable_selected);
}else{
image.setBitmap(R.drawable.my_drawable_normal);
}
```

Comment: can you please guide , how to change  selection based on index position??? and If once click double time on same item, It will be change to deselect mode??